# ImportError even though the module is already installed

Tags: python-2.7

I'm installing packages on virtual env.

```
    (venv)pynanomsg]$ python
    >>> import constants 
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
    ImportError: No module named constants
```

But if I install it using `pip`, it says:

```
$ pip install constants
Requirement already satisfied: constants in      /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `pip install constants` in your virtual environment

```
(venv)$ pip install constants
```